# How to select 100 ordered rows where (column_value = X) to where (column_value = Y)?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with rows that are always changing. Assuming that it is ordered by the registered user ID, some rows are deleted or inserted between others. I want to loop through all of the rows in a limit of 100 per script execution.

something like:

SELECT column_name FROM Table_name WHERE ID>X AND ID

and limited to 100 and ordered by ID column.

I can't use Auto increment row id

Comment: You can use LIMIT

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to search id between 1 and 100, and 100 records, then your query would look like below

```
select your_column
from your_table
where id between 1 AND 100
order by id
limit 100
```

if you use greater than 1 and less than 100, then even if you use 100 in limit, you will not get 100 records, if there were even 100 users with id 1-100, you may  modify like below

```
where id >= 1 AND id <= 100
```

OR just

```
 where id <= 100
```

and if you aren't bothered about `id` just want 100 records then

```
select your_column
from your_table
order by id
limit 100  -- Retrieves first 100 rows
```

For next 100 rows you may use

```
limit 100, 100  -- Retrieves from 101 onwards
```

Comment: How to use WHERE Clause  instead of OFFSET in limit . like  limit (where id= 123), 100